# How to use chrome Plugins in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, java, selenium-webdriver

I want to use chrome Plugins like what font, full page Screen capture. in one of my project, can we write the code for it? Using Selenium web-driver + java.

**I am still on search, is there any workaround for this?**

**Need**:
Take screenshot is works well on **firefox**, works in **chrome** also, but it takes image of only visible part not the full page, so I want to use **chrome Plugins to make error reporting will be easy**.

Comment: Hey Sameer- can you add some more explanation

Comment: @log_file question updated.

Answer (score 1):

A work around I have heard of people doing that wouldn't require any chrome extensions is to resize the window to a large resolution.  If the page in question has a set width, then you can resize the window to that, and then make it very long.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;

Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(600, 5000);
webDriver.manage().window().setSize(screenSize);
```

This won't give you a perfectly sized screenshot that matches the page all the time, and there is a risk that you may still not get the entire page if you're not generous enough.  But this could help you act as a temporary solution that doesn't require much work to accomplish.